# Python re.findall with groupdicts

Tags: python, regex

I kind of wish that there were a version of `re.findall` that returned `groupdict`s instead of just `group`s. Am I missing some simple way to accomplish the same result?

Does anybody know of a reason that this function doesn't exist?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use the finditer() function.  This will give you a sequence of match objects, so you can get the groupdict for each with:

```
[m.groupdict() for m in regex.finditer(search_string)]
```