# Python: Using group names in re.findall()

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python re.findall with groupdicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255332/python-re-findall-with-groupdicts)

In Python, when using a regex pattern with more than one capturing parenthesis, `re.findall(pattern, string [,flags])` returns a list of tuples of strings. This is true even when using the `(?P<name>[pattern])` capturing parenthesis. Is there a way to use findall (or an equivalent function), while maintaining the ability to use the group names later on?